# drag an item out from a scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Am I on the right path trying to drag an item from a UIScrollView and drop it over a second UIScrollView? Neither of the UIScrollViews will be altered in the end, but I'd like to have an image follow the touchMoved position until it's released over second UIScrollView.

I have extended the UIScrollView so I can see where a touch begins inside the UIScrollView.

```
extension UIScrollView {
override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    print("touchesBegan")
    }
}
```

to get the touched object

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        beginningLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
        let position = touch.location(in: itemScrollview)
        print("itemScrollview: \(position)")

        let whoHit = Int(position.x / 120)
        print("whoHit: \(whoHit) \(GameData.items[whoHit].name)")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use touchesEnded to see if the user dragged up, but touchesEnded doesn't always get called. Works if the touches begin and end over the same UIScrollView, but when dragged off, touchesEnd doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo cannot "directly" drag an object (view, image view, label, button, etc) from one view to another (whether it's a UIView or UIScrollView or any other container).

Instead, you need to "move" the object you want to drag from the containing view to the super view (the "main" view), drag it around as a subview of the main view, and then check where it is released.

So, essentially, if you want to drag a UIImageView:

- on first touch, move the image view from its containing view to the "main" view
- translate the coordinates, so they are now relative to the "main" view
- track the touch / drag in main view coordinates, re-positioning the image view as you go
- on release, see if the end touch is inside the "target" container view
- if so, add the image view as a subview of the target view (translating the position coordinates)
- if it's not inside the target frame, either add it back to its original container, or drop it into the main view, or vaporize it, or whatever you desire.

Comment: Seems like if a touch originates inside the UIScrollView, the main view doesn't get any events. Is there a way to have main view touch events at the same time as the scrollview registering hits?

Comment: It's a little complicated, but there are some good examples out there. Here is a "pre-made" option: [link](https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop), or, take a look at this article (and accompanying source code): [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2185202&seqNum=13). Both are Objective-C, but pretty easy to convert to Swift.